# Using Plugin to make mobile sliding navigation but it doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

I am using a plugin/ add on called MMENU - it is being used to create a navigation bar that slides out from the side of the screen (like in the Facebook app). It works in every other browser apart from Internet Explorer, I have also noticed that the nav tag seems to cause a few issues as when I remove it, the jquery functions below it on the page function normally.

The same plugin works on another page but is used in a different area of the page, could it be to do with where it is being used?

Answer (score 0):

I used this plugin and worked well so far in all browsers. The question is not `where it is being used` but `how it is being used`. Check your page structure, check for errors, check css, do not blame the plugin.

Comment: I never questioned whether the plugin works. So you suggest that I go through and see where and how I am using it? My problem is it seems a bit strange that my current structure works in all other browsers.

Comment: For such a general question you cannot get a better answer. It is not strange when something does not work in all browsers, it happens often. I am sure `mmenu` works fine in IE, so the problem is on your side. For details you would have to provide info, would be glad to help.

Comment: That's far enough. Basically I have a div with a link in (so it looks like a button) and when you click on it the side menu appears. I am just confused because I have the function, the div and the content... however when I click on it, it doesn't seem to respond. Is there a way of checking this?

Comment: You have several events where you can debug the code, take a look at documentation [here](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/documentation/custom-events.html)